# What is the right way to reset and restart the animation loop for a game built with JS and HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I have built a simple 2D game that makes use of the CanvasRenderingContext2D interface. There is a 'reset' method on the Game class that is called once the game has ended and the user clicked the 'r' key.

As far as I can tell the method resets the game object correctly but there is an issue with calling the animation function a second time because the `deltaTime` variable is calculated incorrectly. When the animation is first run `deltaTime` is around 16/ 17. When the animation is run again from the reset method, `deltaTime` is equal to the `gameTime` variable or more.

How can I factor in the difference in time when resetting the game?

Here is the animate function:

```
  function animate(timeStamp) {
    const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime
    lastTime = timeStamp
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    game.draw(ctx)
    game.update(deltaTime)
    if (game.gameOver) game.draw(ctx) // draw gameover text on top
    if (!game.gameOver) requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }
```

The rest of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Koda-Pig/2D-game-dev).
A live version of the game is deployed [here](https://main--lively-gelato-cec858.netlify.app/).

I have tried adding another parameter to the animation function, to differentiate the initial animation from the reset animation. Then changing `timeStamp` or `lastTime` variable to `gameTime` or 0 or a new time with the built-in new Date() method, but none of those worked.

```
  function animate(timeStamp, restart) {
    const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime
    if (restart) timeStamp = 0
    lastTime = timeStamp
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    game.draw(ctx)
    game.update(deltaTime)
    if (game.gameOver) game.draw(ctx) // draw gameover text on top
    if (!game.gameOver) requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. I assigned `requestAnimationFrame` to a variable, then used that to properly cancel the previous animation before starting the next one. Then declared a helper variable (`restart`) with its initial value set to false.

The reset method on my main Game class cancels the animation frame and sets the `restart` variable to `true`.

The animation function checks if `restart` is true and if it is, it calls the `update` method on the game with `0` as the argument, instead of the default `deltaTime` variable.

This is what the animation function looks like now:

```
function animate(timeStamp) {
  const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime
  lastTime = timeStamp
  if (restart) {
    game.update(0)
    restart = false
  } else game.update(deltaTime)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  game.draw(ctx)
  if (game.gameOver) game.draw(ctx) // draw gameover text on top
  if (!game.gameOver) requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

And the reset method:

```
reset() {
  if (this.gameOver) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestID)
    restart = true
    // reset game objects
    this.keys = []
    this.enemies = []
    this.particles = []
    this.explosions = []
    this.enemyTimer = 0
    this.enemyInterval = 2000
    this.ammo = 20
    this.ammoTimer = 0
    this.ammoInterval = 350
    this.gameOver = false
    this.score = 0
    this.gameTime = 0
    this.speed = 1
    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }
}
```

If you're interested you can check the rest of the code [here](https://github.com/Koda-Pig/2D-game-dev).